# conditional loading of stylesheet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a site with clients. Every client can have it's own theme and when a user of a certain client is logged in, the company theme must be loaded. In the application.css.scss I have a line like this for every company:

```
@import "_theme_x.css.scss";
@import "_theme_y.css.scss";
@import "_theme_z.css.scss";
```

How can I load only e.g. theme_x when a user of company x is logged in and not load theme_y and theme_z? Or is there a better way of doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If themes are large, you might want to separate them from the application.css and load them conditionally in your layout. For example, if you have a helper `theme_stylesheet` in application_helper which returns the name of the theme the client is using:

```
# application.html.erb
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', theme_stylesheet %>
```

If they are small, I like namespacing. Leave your application.css as-is, but modify the themes to use a top-level rule on the body. Place a tag on the body to select the theme. The beauty of this is you can dynamically change the theme.

```
<body class="theme-<%= theme_stylesheet %>">
  ...
</body>
```

_theme_x.css.scss

```
body.theme-x {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can do it in this manner like you can check first whose client is login and apply some

layout  for him and include diffrent css files for diffrent layout.

Like i do

first i make method in application helper but i can implement layout according user roles you

can do it according clients.

```
  def choose_layout
    if is_admin?(current_user) or is_super_admin?(current_user)
      'admin'
    else
    'application'
  end
```

And in controller call it in before filter than layout will be implement according to user

roles

```
class AdministratorController < ApplicationController

  include ApplicationHelper
  layout :choose_layout

 def index
   @user = User.new
    @current_user = current_user

 end
```

end

hope you could get the idea.....